# Facebbok read_insights permission doesn't seem to work for the ad account

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I can't get insights information from ad account.
I am admin of both ad account and application.

In the Graph API Explorer all fields under insights are grayed out.
It seems like access token doesn't have read_insights permission, but It does. I can see all the permissions in the Access Token Debugger under Scopes: read_insights, manage_pages, ads_read, public_profile

ads_read permission works just fine.

Comment: _“In the Graph API Explorer all fields under insights are grayed out”_ – that doesn’t necessarily mean anything. Add them manually, and see what result you get. Also, check if there are debug messages shown.

Comment: @CBroe Thank you for mentioning debug, I didn't know about it. Request "<AD_ID>/insights?fields=clicks&date_preset=this_year&debug=all" returns nothing (the fields data and debug are empty), while there should be a few hundreds clicks for that particular ad. "?fields=insights{clicks},id" returns only ID, debug is empty as well.

Answer (score 1):

Would have commented but I don't have enough reputation.

Have you figured out this issue? I can't get access to read_insights for some reason and wondered how you did. I am admin for the page and app but I get this error:

```
(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (read_insights) on node type (Page)
```

when I try to do read_insights with access_token in Graph API explorer (i have set the read_insights and all other permissions for the user).

Comment: Well, not exactly. Now it works but i still have no idea why it didn't. 
 My request is as follows: graph.facebook.com/v2.9/<object>/insights?fields=impressions%2C<etc>&date_preset=lifetime&limit=100&level=ad&access_token=<token>.  User access token permissions: ads_management, ads_read, manage_pages, pages_show_list, read_insights.  If you'll figure out why it works (if it will work for you) please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Now it works but i still have no idea why it didn't.
My request is as follows:
graph.facebook.com/v2.9/<object>/insights?fields=impressions‌​%2C<etc>&date_preset‌​=lifetime&limit=100&‌​level=ad&access_toke‌​n=<token>.
User access token permissions: ads_management, ads_read, manage_pages, pages_show_list, read_insights.